# java question on creating small reports

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, swing, report

I need to do a really simple tool that prints reports.
To emphasize I want to be as simple and create it as easier as possible.
I have never looked into reports up today, and would like to ask on an advice on what libraries to use.
The tool will be really simple, i.e. a swing app that a user puts data in a JTable and saves the data.
My thought is to save the data in XML file.
What would be the best way to create a report of the data? I am planning to use multiple of these xml files to create the report.
This is just a first thought so, any design advice/guidance is also welcome

UPDATE:
A user from his machine inputs data e.g.

```
|Date| Name| Job |Description| Result| Reason|Cost| Current Status
```

In a jtable and gives many rows of this kind.  Submits to a central PC and this info is 
is saved in an XML file as a single XML element.
This file can have many of these elements from 1 or N users.  Note that the input is small, and the file will be small. I.e. no high requirements 
From this file I would like to get a report analytically, after some processing on the data, on a description of all these entries and sums on cost.
My only intent is to provide a nice summary in a format easy to understand/view.

Comment: This question is too broad for us to give a reasonable answer. What is a "report"? What is "simple"? What will these reports be used for? Will they have to be transmitted between machines?

Comment: @Lord Torgamus:You are right.Is this update ok?

Comment: Wow, most people don't bother actually updating in response to comments, so kudos to you for following up. At first I thought you had a specific issue that you just weren't explaining. Now it seems like you have an architecture question, in which case this question belongs on Programmers SE. I'll flag for a mod to move this. As for actually generating the report, if you're just asking for a good existing tool, that's off-topic for any SE site.

Comment: @Lord Torgamus:You are right, my main question is a good library for reports, to use inside a simple swing app, and not some library requiring RCP etc.Really small requirements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`JTable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) provides a full implementation of printing for its contents, as discussed in [*Printing Support in Swing Components*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/swing.html).

Comment: I use it with my platform's print-to-pdf driver.

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look to the [Birt project](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/)

Comment: Have you used it?Is it simple to use?

Comment: I used it once by the past (it's been a couple of years now). But Birt is THE Eclipse project when it comes to report generation within the Eclipse ecosystem. Now if you only need to generate a simple table it's maybe a bit over-kill... For a simple table viewer within Eclipse you may have a look to the XViewer project. I use it  for one of my projects and it's pretty easy to setup. It also contains an export feature to CSV (and it also says to HTML but never saw it). More info here http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/xviewer/xviewer.php

Answer (score 2):

...And the winner is [iReport](http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport)!!

Answer (score 1):

There are different Java libraries available for generating reports. The important question is, what format are you expecting the reports in ?

Jasper, which we have used extensively in our project, does a lot of cool stuff.

If you want excel, apache poi is effective.

iText does pdf generation.